# How can I add a bottom "arrow" style to a table element in email html

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am learning the ins and outs of email html. I am using https://www.cerberusemail.com/ cerberus for my email formatting. I chose the hybrid layout as it gave me a lot of information and ability to test my abilities especially with outlook. I want to have at least something at the bottom of my div with the button, as now it is just a block. A slant or arrow at the bottom is what I am looking for, but do not know of the possibilties with older css and html. Thank you in advance. Normally I would use webkit or other options but that is very limited in emails.

```
                    <div style="display:inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 0 70px 50px 0;width:10%; min-width:200px; max-width:330px; vertical-align:top;"
                        class="stack-column">
                        <table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" style="padding: 10px 0px; vertical-align: middle; width: 100px; height:250px; background-color:#c5b2b0;">
                                    <!-- Button : BEGIN -->
                                    <table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin: auto; vertical-align: middle; ">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="button-td button-td-primary"
                                                >
                                                <!--[if mso]>
                                                <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://google.com/" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#1e534e" fillcolor="#1e534e">
                                                    <w:anchorlock/>
                                                    <center>
                                                <![endif]-->
                                                <a href="https://google.com/" style="background: #1e534e; border: 1px solid #1e534e; font-family: serif; font-size: 25px; line-height: 30px; text-decoration: none; padding: 13px 17px; color: #ffffff; display: block; border-radius: 20px;">
                                                    Explore <br> Flourish
                                                </a>
                                                <!--[if mso]>
                                                    </center>
                                                </v:roundrect>
                                                <![endif]-->

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- Button : END -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                    <!--[if mso]>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top" width="330">
                    <![endif]-->
                    <div style="display:inline-block; margin: 0; width:100%; min-width:200px; max-width:330px; vertical-align:top;"
                        class="stack-column">
                        <table valign="right" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding: 0;">
                                    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"
                                        width="100%" style="font-size: 14px; text-align: left;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/310"
                                                    width="310" height="auto" border="0"
                                                    alt="Sustainability, Inclusivity, Transparent, Integrrity"
                                                    style="width: 100%; max-width: 330px; height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555;"
                                                    class="center-on-narrow">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <!--[if mso]>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Can you update the question with how that bottom should look as well? What have you tried so far?